# Django Template `With` Operator complex boolean assignment

Tags: python, django, templates, boolean

I am creating a Django template that has columns only visible to admins. Currently I am using a template tag `has_group` that works well. I have to include some logic for superusers.

```
 {% if request.user|has_group:"Admins" or request.user.is_superuser %}
 <th class="detail_btn_col" scope="col">Detail</th>
 {% endif %}
 ...
 Similar code for the <td>
```

But it's making a query for every row of a table. Not terrible but I would like to just set the value once at the start of the template. I saw that I could assign a variable using `with` and that would accomplish what I want.

```
{% with has_admin_view=request.user|has_group:"Admins" or request.user.is_superuser %}
```

Does not work.

```
{% with has_admin_view=request.user|has_group:"Admins" %}
```

The above works, but superusers aren't included.

**Is there a way to do AND/OR operations in Django template's WITH statement?**

Comment: I understand for this purpose there may be a different way to accomplish the goal, but I would like to know for the future if the WITH statement can take complex Boolean values.